# How do I get my new site ranked the same as my old site?

Tags: 301-redirect

My site was first for all keywords. After a period of time, I converted the domain from abyath.com to abyath.net and that worked well but, after four months, the site is still lagging on the last pages.

Note that there is a site working in the same field and is competition to me. What would be the solution to return my new site to the position of the old site in search engines?